# How to handle multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, relational-database

I have a complex query which requires fields from a total of 4 tables.  The inner joins are causing the query to take much longer than it should.  I have run an EXPLAIN statement, whose visual result is attached below:

[image: EXPLAIN Statement output]

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
FROM
    (pending_corrections
    INNER JOIN cameras ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON (pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500
        OR pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
ORDER BY pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate ASC;
```

How can I achieve the same effect but without the `OR` in one of the joins?

Comment: this joining condition doesn't look good: (pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500
        OR pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno) - in terms of performance... Did you try to use EXISTS(...) subqueries instead of INNER JOINS as you don't select any data from joined tables?

Comment: `OR`ed join conditiona are usially bad (preventing index usage), the common workaround is to rewrite using `UNION`.

Comment: @dnoeth Would you happen to have a suggestion as to how it can be formulated with a UNION instead?

Comment: @Dot NET: 1) Please include your schema definitions when asking for help with queries. 2) a full table scan is not always worse for performance than an index lookup 3) in order to make a guess at whether replacing the full table scan with an indexed lookup, you need to look at the cardinality of *all* the predicates - again missing from your question

Comment: @Dot NET: neat visual representation of the explain plan - what did you use to get it?

Comment: @symcbean - MySQL Workbench. It's a great feature.

Comment: "I have a complex query which requires fields from a total of 4 tables." There is nothing complex in getting 2 fields from a 4 table inner join. Seems that the issues really lies in your database design which causes 2 full table scans...

Comment: @JanneMatikainen - Can you suggest any improvements to the design?

Comment: I'm no mysql expert but adding a view for the table and having Year, Month and Day columns from the seenDate would cause very nice indexes to be used in filtering the pending corrections table for the query. Or you could even make this query into materialized view for even faster access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting as a `UNION` is simple, copy the source and remove one of the `OR`ed conditions in each:

```
SELECT 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
FROM
    (pending_corrections
    INNER JOIN cameras ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON (pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'

union 

SELECT 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
FROM
    (pending_corrections
    INNER JOIN cameras ON pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'

ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Is there an index on `pending_corrections.seenDate`?

Comment: Yes there is an index.  I have tried this statement, however there are still two table scans being carried out.

Comment: Here is the EXPLAIN statement with the above query.  The query is taking very long to execute, so there seems to be something wrong.

http://imgur.com/AF6jlIG

Comment: @DotNET: How many rows are returned? How many rows exist in `pending_corrections` and how many for the WHERE-condition?

Comment: For the WHERE condition there are around 200k rows, and in total there are around 2 million

Answer (score 0):

you may try the following:

```
select 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
from pending_corrections
where pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
  and pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
  and exists(select 1 from cameras where pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_ownership where vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_vrn 
             where pending_corrections.corrected_plate in (vehicle_vrn.vrnno, vehicle_vrn.vrn500))
order by 1,2;
```

or alternatively as dnoeth already mentioned:

```
select * from (
select 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
from pending_corrections
where pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
  and pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
  and exists(select 1 from cameras where pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_ownership where vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_vrn where pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno)
union
select 
   pending_corrections.corrected_plate , pending_corrections.seenDate
from pending_corrections
where pending_corrections.seenDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
  and pending_corrections.seenDate <= '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
  and exists(select 1 from cameras where pending_corrections.camerauid = cameras.camera_id)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_ownership where vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno)
  and exists(select 1 from vehicle_vrn where pending_corrections.corrected_plate = vehicle_vrn.vrn500)
)  by 1,2;
```

PS of course i couldn't test it myself without having the data and knowing all your indexes

Comment: I'm trying the first query which you suggested and am receiving the following error: "Unknown column 'vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno' in where clause".  From what I can see, this is defined in the query, right?

Comment: Just a minor comment, `order by` ordinal position is deprecated (was removed from the ANSI SQL standard in the 90's.) Use column aliases instead.

Comment: fk_sysno -- need to actually JOIN to vrn, not just use in EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

```
      ( SELECT  pc.corrected_plate , pc.seenDate
            FROM  pending_corrections AS pc
            INNER JOIN  cameras AS c ON pc.camerauid = c.camera_id
            INNER JOIN  vehicle_vrn AS v ON pc.corrected_plate = v.vrn500
            INNER JOIN  vehicle_ownership AS vo ON v.fk_sysno = vo.fk_sysno
            WHERE  pc.seenDate >= '2015-01-01'
              AND  pc.seenDate  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH  -- note improved pattern
      )
    UNION  ALL   -- or use DISTINCT if you could have dups
      ( SELECT  pc.corrected_plate , pc.seenDate
            FROM  pending_corrections AS pc
            INNER JOIN  cameras AS c ON pc.camerauid = c.camera_id
            INNER JOIN  vehicle_vrn AS v ON pc.corrected_plate = v.vrnno
            INNER JOIN  vehicle_ownership AS vo ON v.fk_sysno = vo.fk_sysno
            WHERE  pc.seenDate >= '2015-01-01'
              AND  pc.seenDate  < '2015-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
      )
    ORDER BY  corrected_plate , seenDate;
```

You will need

```
pc: INDEX(seenDate)  -- which you said you have
c:  INDEX(camera_id) -- unless you have PRIMARY KEY(camera_id)
v:  INDEX(vrn500)
v:  INDEX(vrnno)
vo: INDEX(fk_sysno) -- sounds like it already exists
```